# Store urls in mysql using tinyurl or similar

Tags: mysql, url, tinyurl

I want to store a large number of unique, indexable urls in mysql. They will be written by the user and will have a really broad acceptance, so almost anything goes there.

But I don't like the already answered [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800866/how-to-store-urls-in-mysql) nor [it's predecessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191587/datatype-for-url). Actually I think there might be a 'better' way for doing so, but I don't completely see the implications of this, so that's why I ask this question.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using tinyurl.com's API for this purpose? In [this link](http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/creating-a-tinyurl-with-tinyurl-api) we can see an article about how to do this. It's just this code (could be even shorter but I prefer it in a function):

```
function createTinyUrl($strURL)
  {
  return file_get_contents("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=".$strURL);
  }
```

Then I would have to compare only the `example` in `tinyurl.com/example` to check the uniqueness of the link. From the wikipedia article we can read:

> If the URL has already been requested, TinyURL will return the existing alias rather than create a duplicate entry.

Disadvantages (basically same ones as using any centralized system):

- Tinyurl servers could go down temporarily or forever. Just in case, the full url will be stored in another not-indexed field.
- Non reversible. You can get a tinyurl from your url, but the other way back is more difficult. However, first problem's solution also solve this.
- In my case, the urls are NOT private, but this could prevent someone from using this solution.
- Delay. The requests might be a bit slower, but since it's server to server talking, I don't think this will be noticeable. Will do some benchmark though.

**Any other disadvantage that you can see using this method?** The main reason for using it is not to have duplicated entries and to make them indexable.

Comment: If you don't care for ordering, a hash-based index on the full URI would be very fast...

Comment: I thought about it, but there might be a problem with collisions in this case. Except for the answer provided in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028213/php5-effecient-hash-generation-with-minimalno-chance-of-collision). I will use that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user eggyal suggested, a hash based index of the full URI is really similar to using the Tinyurl API, only I don't need to send data anywhere. I will use that then.

NOTE: this answer is here only to add closure to the question